# How to compare two arrays and then return the sum of all elements of the array before the changed element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have two arrays that I need to check the difference upon and return the sum of all elements of the array before the changed element and includes him.

I currently have two arrays of area height that get updated when the input's value is changed. Also can be changed 2 or more elements of array, then need sum all changed elements and all elements before last changed element.

For example arrays:

`let oldArea = [3, 4, 2]`

`let newArea = [3, 6, 2]`

I tried something like this (it does its job partially, but the array length can be 5 or more elements, so this solution is bad) :

```js
let oldArea = [3, 4, 2]
let newArea = [3, 6, 2]

let changedArea = [];

if (
  oldArea[0] !== newArea[0] &&
  oldArea[1] === newArea[1]
) {
  changedArea.push(newArea[0]);
} else if (
  oldArea[1] !== newArea[1] &&
  oldArea[0] === newArea[0] &&
  oldArea[2] === newArea[2]
) {
  changedArea.push(newArea[0] + newArea[1]);
} else changedArea.push(newArea.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));

let changedAreaHeight = changedArea.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(changedAreaHeight)
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxwobk93/)

I will be grateful for any tips with other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop and break when the elements are not same

```js
let oldArea = [3, 4, 2]
let newArea = [3, 6, 2]

let final = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < newArea.length; i++) {
  if (newArea[i] === oldArea[i]) {
    final += newArea[i]
  } else {
    final += newArea[i]
    break;
  }
}

console.log(final)
```